# Immutability of Tuple in Python as an object attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, immutability

Is an object attribute, which is of type tuple immutable?
For example if the value of a key of a dictionary is of type tuple, will it still be immutable?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that it *wouldn't* still be immutable?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you're concerned about (e.g. with some code)? Because the tuple is always immutable, but an object with an attribute is generally not. So while you can't mutate the tuple in place, you can easily mutate the object to replace its tuple-valued attribute with some other value (perhaps a different tuple). That may or may not satisfy the immutability requirement you're asking about.

Comment: It is, of course, still immutable. That doesn't mean that you can't set that attribute or bind that key to a **different** object.